# I am trying to make circular dotted line but I am getting square in css

Tags: css

actually I am trying to make a dotted line with CSS I want it in circular form but I am getting it in square

The code I am using is

```
hr {border-style: none; border-top-style: dotted; border-color: grey; border-width: 6px; width: 5%; }
```

The result I am getting is

[image: getting result image]

The result I want is

[image: actual result picture]

can anyone help me with that please.

Answer (score 1):

You have it right in your code. I simplified it a bit by setting `border: none` to undo the default border of `<hr />`. Then I set all of the top border's styles at once with `border-top: dotted grey 15px`:

```css
hr {
  width: 56%;
  border: none;
  border-top: dotted grey 15px;
}
```

```html
<hr />
```

Comment: That's bizarre. I've never noticed that the `dotted` keyword produces square dots in Chrome when the border width is 3px or less, and circle dots when the border width is 4px or higher.

Answer (score 1):

The `dotted` keyword makes square "dots" in most browsers. You'll need to use a custom [border image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) if you want to achieve the effect using the border property. You could also use a background image.

If you want to achieve a similar effect without an image, one approach would be to use multiple [box shadows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow):

```css
hr {
  border: none;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  box-shadow:
    -4rem 0 lightgray,
    -2rem 0 lightgray,
     2rem 0 lightgray,
     4rem 0 lightgray;
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `radial-gradient()`

```css
.hr {
  height:20px;
  background:radial-gradient(circle closest-side,grey 97%,transparent) 
             0 0/30px 100%; /* 20px + 10px of distance between circles */
}
```

```html
<div class="hr"></div>
```

To avoid having partial circles:

```css
.hr {
  height:20px;
  background:radial-gradient(circle closest-side,grey 97%,transparent) 
             0 0/30px 100% round; 
}
```

```html
<div class="hr"></div>
```