# How to get N points in CSS animation without creating N <div>?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I would like to create an infinite animation with that parameters

- a point follow a SVG `<path>`
- there is a choosen amount of points in the animation
- each point is separated with the same distance (so same time)
- there is a non discontinuous generation of points

From [Fun with CSS](https://css-irl.info/fun-with-css-motion-path/) I've managed to get a working demo, but I'd like to scale up that demo with a more complex path (I can handle that part) but the problem is how to get 100 points, or 200 points without creating the same amount of `<div>` in HTML and `--delay` CSS ?

---

**More simple question :** How to build the same demo without 6 `<div>` ? But rather like a variable containing `6` as value, and intermediate delay should be configurable too

```css
svg {width: 500px;}
.wrapper {position: relative;}

:root {
    --delay: 0ms;
    --path: path('m 0 0 h 500');
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2rem;
    background-color: #fbfbf4;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.obj {
    --color: salmon;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    offset-path: var(--path);
    animation: move 6000ms infinite linear var(--delay);
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: var(--color);
}

.obj--2 {--delay: 1000ms;}
.obj--3 {--delay: 2000ms;}
.obj--4 {--delay: 3000ms;}
.obj--5 {--delay: 4000ms;}
.obj--6 {--delay: 5000ms;}

@keyframes move {
    0% {offset-distance: 0%;}
    100% {offset-distance: 100%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="obj"></div>
    <div class="obj obj--2"></div>
    <div class="obj obj--3"></div>
    <div class="obj obj--4"></div>
    <div class="obj obj--5"></div>
    <div class="obj obj--6"></div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 50">
        <path d="m 0 0 h 500" fill="none" stroke="#5e5e7d" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I woud imagine a kind of dotted border where you can control the space between each dot. For a line animation it would be easy like below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66072199/8620333 .. for any path you may create it using SVG

Comment: @TemaniAfif Do you have any link or anything about moving a border or path along itself ?